# How to modify date formate in ajax js code?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a js ajax code:

```
success:function(res){
                var _html='';
                var json_data=$.parseJSON(res.posts);
$.each(json_data,function (index,data) {
                        _html+='<span class='time'>'+data.fields.time+'</span>';
                    });
                $(".post-wrapper").append(_html);
}
```

The issue is the time format is like:

```
2021-08-05T22:10:55.255Z
```

How to modify this date formate to something like:

```
2021-08-05 22:10
```

Comment: Try to use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) instead of momentjs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs for Moment.js, this should do the trick for you: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string+format.

example:
`<span class='time'>'+moment(data.fields.time).format("YYYY-MM-D HH:mm")+'</span>'`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just format it within that success function :

```
var _html='';
var json_data=$.parseJSON(res.posts);
$.each(json_data,function (index,data) { 
    let datetime = data.fields.time;
    let formatted_date = datetime.getFullYear() + "-" + 
    (datetime.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + datetime.getDate() + " " 
    + datetime.getHours() + ":" + datetime.getMinutes();
    _html+='<span class='time'>'+ formatted_date +'</span>';
});
```